# Peformance testing a WCF Webservice with JMeter?

Tags: wcf, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I would like to performance test a webservice hosted on IIS, which exposes a several methods.

The specific operation is get and only requires a single parameter. I was successfully in creating Jmeter script and I get 200 response, however the XML response and logs state a  ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.

The SOAP request was obtained from SOAPUI and is successful in get operation.

I'm confused as to why I'm getting a 200 and not a 500 server error, in addition to the ContractFilter mismatch error.

Has anyone got ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: Please refer to my comment below to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are not using Webservice Sampler as it does not consider 500 status, see this:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54006

Use HTTP Sampler instead.

Also check that you are passing required headers to your webservice putting a HeaderManager as a child of your sampler and adding custom header.

Comment: Hi, new to Jmeter but unsure as to how to specify a specific operation in http request. Can you advise me on how this would be done

Comment: Hi, resolved the issue. Thank you for your assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve issue by using extracting the raw request from SOAPUI and then build a SOAP/XML-RPC request.